# What is I2S and DSP?

Tags: audio, amplifier, terminology, class-d

I am learning to build an amp.([TA2020](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDMQFjAE&url=http://www.e-ele.net/DataSheet/TA2020.pdf&ei=4wlYU__MIcT3rQfW_QE&usg=AFQjCNFMV3-w-Bt29OwlwaLjyaLfEQPY7Q&sig2=vudIftHi1vwKgM4w4NV6VQ&bvm=bv.65177938,d.bmk), circuit from datasheet).

I would like to know about the I2S and DSP, and when and how to integrate these tech. Specifically speaking, if i am suppose to include Bluetooth, USB and Airplay input support to amp, which gives digital output, do I require I2S or DSP or can it be done by simply adding respective modules(if it is possible).

Many high end audio companies(B&O, libratone, etc) have it in there amps. Where do they exactly fit in while building an amp.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I2S is like SPI for audio. DSP is... processing digital signals. If that sounds nebulous, that's because it is.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processing

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sure it is. Can you detail. And when does it needs to be include in amp, more specifically in my case?

Comment: You need it whenever you want the output to not be just an amplification or attenuation of the input.

Comment: If you had control over your audio input source, i2s could be your source. i2s mems microphone breakout - SPH0645LM4H as your guitar pickup or your digital microphone. There may be other guitar midi pickups that use i2s. DSP can incur latency. Especially when tied or embedded in a microcontroller. So keep that in mind. There is a lot more out there for beginners than 4 years ago!

Answer (score 5):

I don't want to discourage you but this project is huge:

- USB,
- Bluetooth (not with simple commands but with a continuous stream of data (audio))
- Airplaiy compatibility
- Signal processing (the DSP part)
- I2S communication to a CODEC
- Analog amp to drive something

Well... This is HUGE! I suggest that you split it into parts. Especially when you say that you are learning and not sure what the DSP is doing.

What I suggest is splitting the work into modules.

First you design your amp with your selected chip. You play with it with a dummy sound source (basic microcontroller producing I2S signal like tones). Then, when you are happy with it, you go to a bluetooth module. Try to implement some bulk transfer and try to obtain the data throughput you will need for audio.

Then, you can think if you need to perform some signal processing that cannot be done on your microcontroller which would justify the DSP.

Then try to put everything together.

If you want to do everything at the same time here is what is likely to happen:

- It's never right the first time. (especially when you are learning) thus you will need to debug and solve issue in all parts. When everything is together and interconnected and interdependent, this is much more complicated to do.
- It's a so difficult project taken as a whole that it will end up in the graveyard of unfinished project...

Comment: i dnt have enuf points to vote up but that was encouraging. thnx a lot. I still got this doubt if it is possible to add bluetooth module to the TA2020 IC. there were many [instructables](http://www.instructables.com) which had amp with [bluetooth capability](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Supercharged-Bluetooth-Speaker-v20/). but the amp was part of the bluetooth module. So basically, what am i suppose to look for in an IC if such tech are to be included.

Comment: i am particularly blurred with the IC specs while expanding the project